# filling array gradually with data from user

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements, fill, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to fill an array with words inputted by user. Each word must be one letter longer than previous and one letter shorter than next one. Their length is equal to table row index, counting from 2. Words will finally create a one sided pyramid, like :
A
AB
ABC
ABCD

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Give the height of array: ");
height = sc.nextInt();
String[] words = new String[height];
for(int i=2; i<height+2; i++){
    System.out.println("Give word with "+i+" letters.");
    words[i-2] = sc.next();
    while( words[i-2].length()>i-2 || words[i-2].length()<words[i-3].length() ){
        words[i-2] = sc.next();
    }
}
```

How can I limit words read from scanner to fill the requirements?Currently the while loop doesn't influence scanner at all :/

This is not a homework. I'm trying to create a simple application and then gui for it.

Comment: Strangely arbitrary requirements, 8 rep, clumpy coding style AND no real question? Definitely homework.

Comment: Aigh. Scanner is so not meant do to that. (is it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You didn't read `height` from `Scanner` (what's the value?)
- Are you sure you're not allowed to use `List<String>` and other dynamically growable data structures?
- What's supposed to happen if the length requirement isn't met?
- Why the `2` and `-2` offset?

  - When `i = 2`, you also access `words[i-3]`. which will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

---

Here's a rewriting that makes the logic clearer:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Height?");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("int, please!");
        sc.next();
    }
    final int N = sc.nextInt();

    String[] arr = new String[N];
    for (int L = 1; L <= N; L++) {
        String s;
        do {
            System.out.println("Length " + L + ", please!");
            s = sc.next();
        } while (s.length() != L);
        arr[L - 1] = s;
    }

    for (String s : arr) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

#### Related questions

- [how to take user input in Array using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622725/how-to-take-user-input-in-array-using-java)
- [How do I keep a scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered? (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)

Comment: data should be read until the requirements are filled. I can use List but still I'll have to limit each inputted word.

Comment: @neville: You can just use `next()` to a temporary variable, and check if it meets condition, and if not, ask again. See my answer, especially the `do-while`.