# How to fill an array of characters from user input?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I googled it a lot and found nothing!
Could someone help me with filling an array of characters from user input, please?

Comment: Show us what you have now and let's work from there ;)

Comment: Must use a different google - "java filling an array of characters from user input" first hit is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622725/how-to-take-user-input-in-array-using-java

Comment: How about we try breaking this into smaller chunks? Start with a search for "java keyboard input" and work from there.

Comment: I know how to fill an array of integers, etc. the problem is with characters.

Comment: @Aura If you know how to do it with integers, use that as a starting point. Try to convert it to use characters, and then post the code here when you are stuck.

Comment: Post your basic code here and we will try to help you out .

Comment: I tried these foolish codes:
`char[] charArr = new char[10];
for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
charArr[i] = (sc.next()).charAt(i);
}`

Comment: @Aura I would add that to your question. It's a good start, what problem did you have with it? It will take the first letter of 10 words.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It makes an infinit loop.

Comment: @ivanovic think that I don't even know how to google a question. Would you please show me one of your search results? here's a place to share our knowledge, isn't it?

Comment: @Aura It won't go around more than 10 times, which is less than infinite.

Comment: @PeterLawrey :-? now it works and i don't know how! tnx anyway...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I googled it a lot and found nothing! Could someone help me with
>   filling an array of characters from user input, please?

My Google said, try this one..

**Option 1 :**

```
    import java.io.*;
   class array {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String tmp = br.readLine();
        int length = tmp.length();
        char c[] = new char[length];
        tmp.getChars(0, length, c, 0);
        CharArrayReader input1 = new CharArrayReader(c);
        int i;
        System.out.print("input1 is:");
        while ((i = input1.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) i);
        }

    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
class array
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter elements...");
        char[] a=sc.next().toCharArray();
        System.out.println("Array elements are : ");
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

*But, in this case, it won't accept after space character.*

**Before, start your coding in Java, you must know these terms :**

[BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

[Exception handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling)

Comment: The problem is with characters, not integers.

Comment: @Aura, then you should mention this, in your question, be clear with your question.

Comment: i have mentioned, both in title and the question.

Comment: @Aura check my updated post. It shows, you didn't tried a single piece of code. These are most basic code, you can find them very easily.

Comment: i'm a beginner. Did u know anything about IOexception or BufferedReader when u start java programming?

Comment: did you know anything about exception handling ??

Comment: i have java course at university and i'm new to it. of course i don't!

Comment: Actually it's my teacher's fault... tnx for ur time and help; i learned a lot.

Comment: @Aura don't blame your teacher, better to take initiative yourself.

Comment: @coders, man!! you were desperate to get the answer accepted? :P

Comment: @LPD hahaha.... no it wasn't like that, actually the way he/she asked the question, `i googled,but didn't find anything`, that's why, i was just showing him/her. I found all this from google. ;)

Answer (score 1):

//more fun ...............

```
public class test3 {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char crr[]=new char[100];
        Scanner inputs=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the string");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            char c=inputs.next().charAt(0);
            crr[i]= c;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(" " +crr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Have been looking for a way to sort an array full of characters that were inputted by the user. `public static void main(String[] args) {
 char crr[]=new char[10];
        Scanner inputs=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 10 Letters: ");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            char c=inputs.next().charAt(0);
            crr[i]= c;
        }
        System.out.println("The Sorted Letters are: ");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
         Arrays.sort(crr); 
            System.out.println(" " +crr[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to read a word and split it into an array of characters you can use.

```
char[] chars = scanner.next().toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   /* program below takes an string from user, splits into character and display as array of characters. */  

     package com.demo.mum;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;

        /**
         * @author cyruses
         * 
         */

        public class CharacterArray {

            public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println("Enter the string:");
                String tmp = br.readLine();
                int strLen = tmp.length();
                char c[] = new char[strLen];
                for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                    c[i] = tmp.charAt(i);
                }
                System.out.println("Displaying character Array");
                for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(c[i]);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is part of my program for linear searching, I fixed the issue I was facing. But I want explanation about why I was getting exception on charAt(x) and not on charAt(0).

```
        System.out.println("Enter Your Data in character");
        for(x=0;x<char_array.length;x++)
        {
        Scanner input_list_char = new Scanner(System.in);
        char_array[x]=input_list_char.next().charAt(0); //it works
        char_array[x]=input_list_char.next().charAt(x); // give me exception
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To input a character array from user

```
import java.io.*;
class CharArrayInput {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    /*using InputReader and BufferedReader class 
      to fill array of characters from user input.
    */
    InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
    //Take size of array from user.
    System.out.println("Please enter size of array")
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    //Declare a character array
    char arr[] = new char[n];
    //loop to take input of array elements
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = (char)br.read();
    }   

   }
  }
```

Comment: That's rather a large chunk of code without any explanation of what you're doing or where the results end up.

Answer (score 0):

You can't take input directly in charArray using nextChar() because there is no nextChar() in Java. You first have to take input in String then fetch character one by one.

```
import java.util.*;
class CharArray{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in); 

    char ch[]=new char[11];

    String s = scan.nextLine();

    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)  
    ch[i]=s.charAt(i);  //Input in CharArray

    System.out.println("Output of CharArray: ");
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) 
        System.out.print(ch[i]); //Output of CharArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will not work if user print input in form of string like as...

```
5 8
########
#..#...#
####.#.#
#..#...#
########
```

**in this if we use `char c=inputs.next().charAt(0);` it will take only first of every string ,**

It will be better to use

```
    *Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    int m = s.nextInt();
    char[][] in = new char[m+1][n+1];
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
        String st = s.next();
        for(int j = 0;j<m;j++) {
            in[i][j] = st.charAt(j);
        }
    }*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class charinarray
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter char elements...");
    char[] a=input.next().toCharArray();
    System.out.println("Array char elements are : ");
    for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).