# sum of array past user input

Tags: java, arrays

hi guys new to programming and to stack overflow. I was wondering if i could get a few pointers, so basically i've made an array holding values of 1-200. But now i would like to be able to ask the user for input and then add together the remaining numbers in the array.

e.g. user enters 100 - so then all numbers from 100 - 200 are added together and then the total outputted.

I have a feeling it will be something really simple I just don't know where to start.

Thanks Guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622725/how-to-take-user-input-in-array-using-java

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 3):

> I just don't know where to start.

1. Write a HelloWorld programm to learn how to output something.
2. Write a program which reads some input values, in different datatypes.
3. Learn how for-loops work.
4. Put all your knowledge together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a the `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);` to ask an input from the user...

Then simply use a for loop starting from the inputted value to the end of the array and sum the results..

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = inputtedValue ; i < 200 ; i++)
{
   sum += array[i];
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

**EDIT**

For better understanding for the OP I am editing my answer posting the complete code, although it is not how stackoverflow works.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputtedValue = s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();
    int[] array = new int[200];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 200 ; i++)
    {
       array[i] = i+1;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = inputtedValue ; i < 200 ; i++)
    {
       sum += array[i];
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

input: 199
output: 200

input: 100
output: 15050

input: 0
output: 20100

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. i have used to above code which you suggested and it now makes sense to me :) but the sum is outputting at 0 every time. have i done something wrong?

Comment: I edited my answer with the full code... how this helps you understanding how it works.