# ArrayList or Array? Not sure what kind of declaration this is

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] paths = new ArrayList[N];
```

This line is part of a code given to me in an Assignment to use as part of Djikstra's algorithm.
Since it was given to me in the assignment I assume it's syntactically correct but I don't think I've ever seen an `ArrayList` being declared with the brackets used to declare Arrays.

Is this an `ArrayList` or an Array? What do the brackets mean in this case?

Comment: seems to be an array of arraylists

Comment: I recommend *not* to mix arrays and `ArrayList`s.

Comment: Why not mix Arrays and ArrayLists?

Comment: @testo Because arrays have limited flexibility, and since you're already using a list (imposing a small overhead), so there is no need to also use an array. [More about the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391553/why-is-it-preferred-to-use-lists-instead-of-arrays-in-java). Also, arrays don't work well with generics. E.g. `new ArrayList<T>` is valid, but `new T[0]` isn't.

Comment: I would say a reason to not mix them is that it's hard to read and understand quickly... `Integer[][]` is easy to read and `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` is easy to read, but that is just confusing at first glance.

Answer (score 5):

An array of ArrayList-Instances.

Answer (score 3):

to be very exact (or even pedantic), it is an array with `N` elements: 
 `= new ArrayList[N]`.

Each element itself can be an `ArrayList` - but after that statement, the array is just filled with `null`s.